# Spring MVC app works in Eclipse with Tomcat 9.0 version, but not working on CLI via tomcat startup.bash file

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat, jersey, java-17

I've a spring MVC multimodule app and it works great in Eclipse with Tomcat 9 but when I try to run in on external Tomcat server using startup.bash option server starts but app doesn't work.

```
05-Apr-2023 13:42:42.747 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
05-Apr-2023 13:42:42.924 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [78146] milliseconds
05-Apr-2023 13:43:10.200 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:in.wm
```

After this line nothing happens. But when it comes to Eclipse this line:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:in.wm`
```

comes during app startup and it scans the root resources but external server does not scan anything and it just start and after startup just stuck on that line.

Also I get stack trace in `localhost.log` file.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.73

I want this Jersey to scan this resources and work like it works in Eclipse.

Comment: get this error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 59766 outofbounds for length 35487
org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:133)
 com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner$1.f(FileSchemeScanner.java:86)
com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scanDirectory(FileSchemeScanner.java:83)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75937553/edit) your question, improve the formatting (it seems some lines has the wrong formatted and some line breaks got lost) and include the complete stack trace from your comment with information when you get it where.

Comment: Note that Tomcat isn't "stuck". It has started up and doesn't have anything else to do. That log coming from Jersey is being handled by an HTTP processing thread, which shows that your application is indeed running and handling requests (such as the one which caused Jersey to perform some initialization). It seems that your application cannot initialize properly due to that exception. Can you post the whole stack trace (edit the question and put it in there, not in a comment).

Comment: Are you using **exactly** the same version of Java to run both?

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I got to conclusion that Eclips somehow provides all required resources and make the app run with jersey 1.17, java 17 , tomcat 8. But when I try it from tomcat directory it  fails because of jersey and java compatibilty.

Comment: I tried same app in the home environment with java 7 and tried to run using startup.bash it worked.

Comment: So I'm now trying to upgrade jersey to newer version 2.33 or newer.